# how to remove Error for schema bindings in redshift

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

I want to be able to make CTE to make the below SQL work, I am getting the error
`ERROR:  Cannot replace a normal view with a late binding view` for the below SQL, any way I could change it up so that it doesnt bind with schema views?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
  VIEW "dev"."XXBRK_DAILY_FX_RATES" ("F_C", "CURRENCY", "C_D", "C_R") AS
  SELECT DISTINCT GL.GL_R.F_C, GL.GL_R.CURRENCY, 
GL.GL_R.DATE, GL.GL_R.C_R
FROM GL.GL_R
with no schema binding
WHERE GL.GL_R.C_T='Corporate'
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT GL.GL_R.F_C, GL.GL_R.F_C CURRENCY, GL.GL_R.DATE, 1 
FROM GL.GL_R;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you seem to have a statement issue.  The last 4 lines are after the ';' and not part of the statement being run.  I'm guessing that these are extraneous and posted by mistake.

Views on Redshift come in several types - normal and late binding are 2.  The view "dev"."XXBRK_DAILY_FX_RATES" seems to already exist in your cluster so your command is trying to replace it, not create it.  The error message is correct, you cannot replace a view with a view of a different type.  You need to drop the view, then recreate it as late binding.

Now be careful as other objects dependent on this view will be impacted when you drop it (especially if you CASCADE the drop).  When you drop and recreate the view it is a new object in the database but replacing a view just make a new definition for the same object.  Understand the impacts of drop to your database before you execute it.

Comment: ahh i see the semi colon above was a mistake, i dropped the view and tried the code again but i seem to get syntax error at around WHERE now, I'm not sure what's wrong

Comment: The "with no schema binding" needs to be at the end (right before the ;).  Right now it is in the middle of the select statement that defined the data returned by the view.  Moving this will just get you back to your original error message as you are trying to change view type.

Comment: aahh then how can i remove the error message and make sure it runs properly? after dropping the view ofcourse